# Why does the command "Timeout" in a batch file suddenly not work anymore?

Tags: windows, batch-file, timeout

Did I miss a change of the Windows internal "timeout" command?

I have a batch file for a long time now that shows me the version number of a program. I added the timeout command to keep the CMD window opened for a few seconds. So my batch file now looks like this:

```
context -version
timeout 7
```

This worked fine but since some Windows update (obviously), the CMD windows closes directly as if the timeout command doesn't work anymore. When I start the file from a CMD window I get a message:

> D:\CTX>**timeout 7**
>   Try 'timeout --help' for more information.

The file is as it was since I created it, but the behavior is new to me.

So can anybody tell me what I is going wrong here?

Comment: Timeout is still working fine in a batch file on my updated version of Windows 10. Perhaps try add the -NOBREAK paramater (Just taking a chance), or "timeout /T 7"

Comment: Change it to read `timeout.exe 7` or `"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" 7` If it works fine, as I expect it to, you'll probably find that your script or another executable local file named `timeout` with a different extension is causing your issue. _(Running the command given by Magoo should also identify this scenario)_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you've probably acquired a different version of `timeout` since the help prompt `--help` is a `\*nixy` style option-specifier.

Try, from the prompt

```
where /T timeout.*
```

which should list the `timeout` versions on the `path` and may assist in locating the rogue version.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. After using *where* command I noticed that cygwin64, that I installed a few weeks ago, was in the path before system32. I just had to change the order and now it works again...

Comment: Thanks so much! In my case it was because I ran it from R using `shell()` and `shell.exec()`. In the PATH, my version of Rtools was preceding the system32 folder.

Answer (score 8):

**TIMEOUT** is not an internal command of `cmd.exe` (Windows Command Processor) like **FOR** or **DIR**.

It is an external command which means a console application being located in the Windows system directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

On using just `timeout` without file extension and without full path, the Windows command interpreter searches first in the current directory with `timeout.*` for a file having a file extension listed in the **local** environment variable **PATHEXT**.

If no such file can be found in current directory, the Windows command interpreter continues the search for `timeout.*` with a file extension listed in **PATHEXT** in the directories defined in the **local** environment variable **PATH**.

The **system PATH** is defined as follows on Windows Vista and later versions of Windows:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

For that reason it is usually found first `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` on using just `timeout` in a batch file.

But if the current directory contains a file with name `timeout.*` having a file extension listed also in environment variable **PATHEXT**, or **PATH** was redefined locally or system wide by an installer which put other directory paths at the beginning instead of appending them at the end, and one of these directories contains also a `timeout.*` file, the Windows command interpreter runs this executable or script.

The suggestions for solving this problem:

1. Use in the batch file `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` because then the Windows command processor must not search for this executable and it can't happen that the wrong `timeout` is executed mistakenly, except the environment variable `SystemRoot` is modified locally which is very unlikely in comparison to `PATH` manipulations.
2. Open Windows **Control Panel - System and Security** (on *View by: Category* selected) **- System - Advanced system settings** (blue link on left side), select tab **Advanced** and click on button **Environment Variables...** There can be also clicked on Windows **Start** button and entered on keyboard **environment** and Windows suggests in the menu **Edit environment variables for your account** and **Edit the system environment variables** in the language of Windows. Click the latter suggested item and if necessary depending on Windows version next on button **Environment Variables...** Then search in lower half in list of **System variables** for **Path**, select this environment variable, click on **Edit**, and move all directory paths left or above (depends on Windows version) of `%SystemRoot%\system32` to the end of the directories list.
3. Please report to the author of the application or software bundle which modified **system PATH** and inserted their directory paths at beginning instead of appending them at end about this wrong modification of Windows **system PATH**.

As [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) wrote already: a `timeout.*` ported from Unix to Windows is obviously executed on your Windows machine because of the output help statement. To get help on a command on Windows, the command has to be executed usually with parameter `/?` and not with `-h` or `--help` as on Unix.

Comment: a very detailed and informative answer. thank you very much.

Comment: Your detailed answer helped me a lot. Thanks :)